# Testing the significance of interaction terms with multcomp::glht()

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, ordinal-data, ordered-probit

I am estimating an ordinal logistic regression under the assumption of proportional odds with the ordinal::clm() function. As a RE see this model from the "housing" dataset (`MASS::housing`):

```
clm(Sat~Type*Cont + Freq, data = housing, link = "probit") %>% S

formula: Sat ~ Type * Cont + Freq
data:    housing


Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
TypeApartment          -0.14387    0.54335  -0.265    0.791
TypeAtrium              0.20043    0.55593   0.361    0.718
TypeTerrace             0.18246    0.55120   0.331    0.741
ContHigh                0.05598    0.53598   0.104    0.917
Freq                    0.01360    0.01116   1.219    0.223
TypeApartment:ContHigh -0.25287    0.78178  -0.323    0.746
TypeAtrium:ContHigh    -0.17201    0.76610  -0.225    0.822
TypeTerrace:ContHigh   -0.18917    0.76667  -0.247    0.805

Threshold coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value
Low|Medium   -0.1130     0.4645  -0.243
Medium|High   0.7590     0.4693   1.617
```

If I want to test if the main effect and the interaction term are (simultaneously!) significant I used the glht function where I test the hypothesis that (bold for matrices or vectors) $\boldsymbol{\beta} \cdot \boldsymbol{K} = \boldsymbol{m}$.

So If I'd like to test if living in an apartment (main effect) **plus** the interaction of living in an apartment and having high contact is significantly different from zero it would be $(0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0;0 )\cdot \boldsymbol{\beta} = (0;0;...;0)$. (Assuming the two thresholds as intercepts and thus the first two estimates).

Is it right to test:

```
glht(mod, linfct = c("TypeApartment +TypeApartment:ContHigh  =0")) %>% summary()

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: clm(formula = Sat ~ Type * Cont + Freq, data = housing, link = "probit")

Linear Hypotheses:
                                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
TypeApartment + TypeApartment:ContHigh == 0  -0.3967     0.6270  -0.633    0.527
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

or do I have to use:

```
glht(mod, linfct = c("TypeApartment= 0", "TypeApartment:ContHigh  =0")) %>% summary()

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: clm(formula = Sat ~ Type * Cont + Freq, data = housing, link = "probit")

Linear Hypotheses:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
TypeApartment == 0           -0.1439     0.5434  -0.265    0.946
TypeApartment:ContHigh == 0  -0.2529     0.7818  -0.323    0.921
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Thanks a lot in advance I hope I posed the question right and understandable :-) If you have other options to test if a main effect and an interaction term are significant go ahead and tell me (and the others).

Thanks, Luise

Comment: When you say "plus" what do you mean as the null hypothesis? Is it that the sum of the coefficients equals 0? Or that both of the coefficients equal 0?

Comment: Hey, my H_o was if the maineffect and the interaction term are at once zero. To now I think that the "maineff+interaction=0" is wrong because it could be that 0.2*beta_1 + 0.8*beta_2 =0. For now I did the car::LinearHypothesis like an global F-Test... But this only test if all variables make sense. I'm still not sure if this is correct.

Comment: I replaced your `multivariate-analysis` tag with the `multiple-regression` tag. The word "multivariate" is most precisely used to describe multiple outcomes, although that usage is far from universal.

Comment: Crossposted on SO:  [Testing the significance of interaction terms with multcomp::glht()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71531275/8239061)

Comment: thanks @EdM I'm sorry for that

Comment: And aso thanks @SecretAgentMan :-)

Comment: You are far from the only person to confuse multiple regression with multivariate regression. I've done that in publications at least once myself.

Answer (score 1):

These are related to [Wald tests on multiple coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Test(s)_on_multiple_parameters) that take into account the covariances among the coefficient estimates. The [multcomp package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=multcomp) that provides the `glht()` function also can correct for multiple comparisons. The correct form depends on precisely which null hypothesis you want to test.

If your null hypothesis is that both the `TypeApartment` and the `TypeApartment:ContHigh` coefficients are simultaneously equal to 0, then the second form tests that hypothesis. The first form tests the hypothesis that the *sum* of those two coefficients is 0, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

I'm not assessing whether that particular null hypothesis makes sense for these data. It can be hard to figure out on your own exactly which set of coefficients to test when there are interactions or nonlinear terms in a regression.

You might consider using the `lrm()` or `orm()` functions in the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) for your ordinal regression modeling. The `anova()` function for models in `rms` directly provides Wald tests that evaluate all terms associated with a predictor and thus can avoid a lot of confusion and potential errors. There can be something of a learning curve with that package, but it's worth it if you do much regression modeling.

Comment: Thank you! Yes for now I did a Chisq test with car::linearHypothesis(mod, c("main_term=0", "interaction=0")). And I already tried to work with the rms package but had some problems and not that much time to read on how it works.... I think the direction and the "main idea" of a model will be identical though. F.e. MASS::polr() and ordinal::clm() get identical results. What I really recommend are the spline functions rather than dichotomizing a numerical value.

Comment: Thanks @EdM, the thing I wondered about was that I don't get a single value if I plug in (mod, linfct= c("main_term=0", "interaction=0"))into the glht. For now (see comment) I did a Chisq test with the car::linearHypothesis(). Would you say the latter is wrong or reasonable?

Comment: @Eco007 `ghlt()` seems to be focused on multiple-comparison corrections. I assume that's why it provides separate corrected p-values for each of the requested tests. (I don't use it; I might be wrong.) A single Wald (chi-square) test that evaluates all coefficients of interest together, as `anova()` in `rms` performs (and perhaps what `linearHypothesis()` does; I don't use that either) should be fine. I also resisted diving into `rms` at first. My regret is that I didn't overcome that resistance a lot earlier than I did. Once you get into it, it makes many things a lot simpler.